# Emulate instruments with MIDI keyboard

Tags: windows, audio, music-production, midi

I am looking for a program (preferably lightweight and free) that lets me use a Casio keyboard with MIDI to play or emulate an array of instruments.

I am not looking into audio production at all so programs like FL Studio or the like aren't required. So bottom line, I am looking just for an emulator of natural instruments running on Windows 10 64-bit, nothing more.